# How can I get RxDataSource to work

Tags: observable, rx-swift, rxdatasources

Do I need to add as a pod?
I need to create a sectioned tableView with RxCocoa UI binding. I have not been able to find the right documentation to implement it.
thanks in advance

this is my Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'NetworkLayer-Rx' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for NetworkLayer-Rx
  pod 'RxAlamofire'
  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxCocoa'

  target 'NetworkLayer-RxTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes RxDataSources is a separate pod and you thus need to add it to your Podfile.

Installation is explained on the RxDataSources repo:
https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources#installation